# Getting Error while using helper method -- helper is not a function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am trying to implement helper method in my lightning component but getting below error.

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: sree123:calculate$controller$calculateResult [helper.calHelper
>   is not a function] Failing descriptor:
>   {sree123:calculate$controller$calculateResult}.

Please help me out.

Here is my component:

calculate.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="AuraCalculations">
    <aura:attribute name="FirstNumber" type="decimal"/>
    <aura:attribute name="SecondNumber" type="decimal"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Result" type="decimal"/>
   <div>
       <ui:inputnumber value="{!v.FirstNumber}" label="First number"/>
       <ui:inputnumber value="{!v.SecondNumber}" label="Second number"/>
       <ui:inputnumber value="{!v.Result}" label="Result"/>
       <ui:button press="{!c.calculateResult}" label="Calculate" />
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

calculateController.js:

```
({
    calculateResult : function(component, event, helper) {
         helper.calHelper();

    }
})
```

Helper Method :calculateAppHelper.js:

```
({
    calHelper : function(component) {
        var fnumber = component.get("v.FirstNumber");
        var snumber = component.get("v.SecondNumber");
        //var result = fnumber+snumber;
        var action = component.get("c.calci");
        action.setParams({"fstNumber":fnumber,"scdNumber":snumber});
        action.setCallback(this,function(data){
            alert(data.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.Result",data.getReturnValue());

        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action);


    }
})
```

Apex Class - AuraCalculations.aprx :

```
public class AuraCalculations {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static decimal calci(decimal fstNumber,decimal scdNumber){

        return(fstNumber+scdNumber);
    }


}
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your question and post the code with proper formatting. It's not readable that much.

Comment: While you post your formatted code, I can see in this version that you are trying to call *helper.calHelper();* whereas your function is defined as *calHelper : function(component)* -- you are missing to pass *component* from your controller.

Comment: Hi Jayant, Even after placing component also getting same error

Answer (score 2):

From the method definition of calHelper() needs a parameter "component". While calling the method you are not passing it and hence your helper method isnt getting called.

Solution: pass the parameter to helper.

```
({
    calculateResult : function(component, event, helper) {
         helper.calHelper(component);

    }
})
```

Code working:

[image]

Comment: Yeah i did the same but still getting same error !!

Comment: @user56612 make sure you refresh/clear cache before trying to run this again

Comment: I quickly tried your code and got a proper response, that you wanted. As @Jayant mentioned.. You need to refresh your window. I do a hard refresh using CTRL+F5, it works.

Comment: Hi Jayant, I cleared cache and tried again but still getting same error.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Let me check once again

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, Jayant Das Thanks alot for immediate response :) but still i am getting same error even though i cleared cache and also did refresh. There might be problem with my browser or something

Comment: @user56612 I can upload my code as Github repo if that helps.. I literally tried your code..

Comment: Do we have a solution for it? I am also facing similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write helper logic in component helper(calculateHelper.js). In the above code posted by you, the logic is in calculateAppHelper.js. please move the helper logic from calculateAppHelper.js to calculateHelper.js then it should work.